# Get image for captcha session

Tags: java, captcha

I want to get the current captcha that is displayed on a website. An example of this would be 
http://top100arena.com/in.asp?id=58978

How would I get the image link of the captcha that is displayed other than right clicking - > open image in new page?

Comment: If you want to do it in Java, you're going to have to parse the page and come up with some kind of heuristic for determining if you've parsed a captcha image or just a regular image.

Comment: The issue with parsing the page is that you get this:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeyFroSAAAAAJTmR7CLZ5an7pcsS5eJ3wEoWHhJ

Which changes the challenge every time you open it, so you wouldn't get the same challenge on the page. The challenge key is what displays the image here:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=#challengekey

Comment: how you want it to be done? You want that your java program works in background and whenever you open a site in your browser that has a captcha, the program will copy the url to a log or database or what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the div identified by `"rechapta_image"`:
[image]

Then extract the `src` attribute of the img element inside this div.

To do this, you can choose for an easy String-operation-based way or use a HTML parsing library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Here is an example of such an extract URL:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VutGj3wvhGoQGxu6FUnG3uOWJdyB2RpSb2N5v9AQJyakMy1kKMPeDoRfADhjAj5rLqekuOzXe3cRChnA_sEN7PL68em4pI_kE3wFKUhhkqFF9jQzKJerX__InwD_DB0Ox1mKQmZVRl97yuSL62tZhYyhSqtuIta-3n0KvytB9QqSn8nXgw8

---

Actually, it seems that the chapta box is an iframe. So  search for an iframe with src string containing "chapta". Example of such a iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscriptk=6LeyFroSAAAAAJTmR7CLZ5an7pcsS5eJ3wEoWHhJ"
   height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
```

So, once you extracted that URL, use JSoup again to find the URL to the image. The page fetched has a part this:

[image]

So, look for a center element, and get the img element out of it.

Comment: How are you getting this to show up? This is not in the page source code.

Comment: In Google Chrome, right click and click "Inspect Element". A similar feature is available in Safari and Firefox as well. I think you have to turn on developer tools in the Safari settings if you are using Safari.

Comment: Use, JSoup as I suggested in my answer. And use `Elements div = document.select("div#rechapta_image");` too get the div.

Comment: Printing out the div object prints out "" from the document.select("div#recaptcha_image").

Comment: Yes, you should fetch the img element inside and then ask for the src attribute. While debuggin, you might try `document.select("div#rechapta_image").html()` and print that out.

Comment: The issue from what I can see is that jsoup is only getting the html text, but the inspect element shows more than the html text. Viewing the source code of the website won't show this:

    <img style="display:block;" alt="reCAPTCHA challenge image" height="57" width="300" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuuCzsLTyUWsctPz1idwcUMSpUQCPHmYE4W-oexFs0LhbflbIhhZWwQTNZqM6SqcsKWiOPNSnylgvlliZVa6bVgkEYoE2fNIDpYcHuomVhzsgY7A0ZoNYqq49oufGJnQgh0bkykt1H2fbZUNTa984kAB68H1PLSWHqY3DHwLidSrzZEwrbs">

Comment: The issue with parsing http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LeyFroSAAAAAJTmR7CLZ5an7pcsS5eJ3wEoWHhJ is that the captcha changes every time you visit that url, so it won't be the original image from the first time you visited the page with the captcha.

Comment: I would say "deal with it!" :) You are the one solving the problem here. I'm not going to do everything for you.

Comment: That is because I'm not giving you a solution but a set of tips, hints and tools to work with. Now use them and make the solution by yourself. The fact that the chapta changes when you reload the page is not such a big deal. Just make sure to keep track of the form action.

Comment: It's a big deal. You can't get the current captcha on the page unless you can get the inspect element text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firebug in firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/firebug/, Its easy to use and in the Red section you´ll find a label named Image, you´ll find the image there.